# Automate File Upload using Selenium Webdriver C# on ASP.NET file upload control

Tags: file-upload, selenium, automation, webdriver

I have a ASP.NET file upload control which opens a window when you click the upload button to select the file you want to upload. But the problem is that the webdriver cant recognize the window and therefore cant select the file to be uploaded.

I have found numerous solutions in the stackoverflow which use sendkeys to enter the path of file. I think that works when you have html file upload control. In my case I have the ASP.NET file upload control and it doesn not have a text box where i can enter the file path using sendkeys.

how do i solve this?? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Windows Automation library to identify windows. UIspy can be used to identify the properties of a window. Add the `System.Windows.Automation` reference to your project.